# How to delete the number of current messages that are only older than 30 days in WL JMS Queues using WLST

Tags: jms, wlst

I am trying to use the cmo.deleteMessages to clean up messages that are older than 30 days.

```
connect(...)
domainRuntime()

print 'Cleaning Message from QUEUE:myqueue'
try:
        cd('ServerRuntimes/myserver/JMSRuntime/myserver.jms/JMSServers/myserver/Destinations/JMSMODULE!JMSmyserver@myqueue')
        cmo.deleteMessages("JMSTimestamp > 5200000000")
except:
        pass
```

However Weblogic doesnt recognize the attribute "JMSTimestamp > 5200000000". It deletes all the messages.
When I put the entry "JMSTimestamp > 5200000000" in the Message Selector [in wl console], it shows up all messages instead of messages that are only 30 days old [5200000000 milliseconds is 30 days].

The problem is the format "JMSTimestamp > 5200000000" is either not recognized by Weblogic or the python script. Any idea what I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to create the timestamp in milliseconds using a modified date command tool in Linux.

```
$ date +%s%N | cut -b1-13
1617374452236
```

JMS time stamp parameter accepted this format and was able to perform the task.